# Linking gtest based application on windows: visual studio and cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cmake, googletest

For linux I used the following cmake rules to build and link an executable that runs unit tests for my library (bt_lib):

```
set(TEST_EXECUTABLE unit_tests)

include_directories(
                 $ENV{GMOCK_ROOT}/include
                 $ENV{GMOCK_ROOT}
         $ENV{GMOCK_ROOT}/gtest
         $ENV{GMOCK_ROOT}/gtest/include
               )

add_executable(${TEST_EXECUTABLE} test1.cpp ../${PROJECT_H}) 

target_link_libraries(${TEST_EXECUTABLE}
                        bt_lib
                        gtest
                        gtest_main
                        pthread
                        gmock
                        )
```

CMake generates visual studio project files and I can build my library and gmock/gtest without problems. But the actual test requires pthread which is not available on windows.

Can I have a check which OS I am configuring for and link $TEST_EXECUTABLE to something else than pthread if I am on Windows? If so, how?

I must add that I am a beginner in most things c++ on windows so even fairly trivial things would need an explanation. I think that using visual studio is they way I want to go though (not something like http://www.mingw.org/).

Comment: You might be interested in the solution in http://docs.biicode.com/examples/google-test-tutorial.html, I have tried both in Visual2008-2010 and Mingw and works pretty well. Basically they retrieve and configure googletest automatically in your proyect with CMake. There is also the Gmock library, tough I havent tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, pthread do not exist natively in windows, as it is a POSIX specification. If your code has pthread_create and the like functions, you need a port of pthreads for windows, e.g:

- http://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/
- http://web.cs.du.edu/~sturtevant/w13-sys/InstallingpthreadsforVisualStudio.pdf

When you download and install the pthread port, you should specificy typically the INCLUDE and LINK directories:

```
IF (WIN32)  
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(your_path_to_pthreads_includes)
    LINK_DIRECTORIES(your_path_to_pthreads_lib)
ELSE(WIN32)
```